# Twilio ReqestValidator always returns false

Tags: .net, security, twilio

When using Twilio's RequestValidator, the .Validate function always returns false. I'm not sure if I'm just missing something, or if I'm actually using incorrect information.  The code is below:

```
    public ActionResult Text(string messageSid, string body, string to, string from)
    {
        var validator = new RequestValidator(AuthToken);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                         {
                             {"Body", body},
                             {"From", from},
                             {"MessageSID", messageSid},
                             {"To", to}
                         };

        var signature = Request.Headers["X-Twilio-Signature"];
        var url = @"https://e5f89299.ngrok.io/Home/Text";

        var b = validator.Validate(url, parameters, signature);
}
```

I put the parameters in alphabetical order, and the url is the exact one I provide for Twilio. The signature looks right as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looking at your code and you're almost doing it right, but as it turns out, Twilio will make a request to your application passing a lot more information than what you're actually expecting, and in retrospective, I do appreciate that maybe our documentation doesn't really show that.

I've created a sample application [here](https://github.com/mplacona/TwilioRequestValidator) that shows an example that works with the current version of the API. But basically, it all boils down to instead of hard-coding the parameters, you could do something similar to what I did in this:

```
public IActionResult SendMessage(IFormCollection fc)
{
    // The Twilio request URL
    const string url = "https://31123028.ngrok.io/api/Message";

    // Initialize the validator
    var validator = new Twilio.Security.RequestValidator(_authtoken);

    // The X-Twilio-Signature header attached to the request
    var twilioSignature = "empty";
    StringValues headerValues;
    if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Twilio-Signature", out headerValues))
    {
        twilioSignature = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(twilioSignature);

    var parameters = fc.Keys.ToDictionary<string, string, string>(key => key, key => fc[key]);

    var hashedParameters = GetHashedParameters(url, parameters);
    Console.WriteLine(hashedParameters);
    Console.WriteLine(validator.Validate(url, parameters, twilioSignature));

    return Content("blah");
}
```

As you can see, I'm looping through all the parameters passed in and then adding them to a dictionary, which I then pass into the `Validate` method.

```
var parameters = fc.Keys.ToDictionary<string, string, string>(key => key, key => fc[key]);
```

I've also added some debugging and a method to show me that I'm generating the same hash as Twilio.

Hope this helps you out.